# What is the best integer n-tuple hash in python?

Tags: python, hash, tuples

Adopting from the [Java Array class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html) (lines 2938-2947) we can do:

```
def java_like_hash(tup):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: 31*x+y, (1,)+tup)
```

But is this optimal for python?

Comment: I'm confused ... what's wrong with `hash(tup)`?  It seems that the python devs would use whatever hashing function they thought optimal ...

Comment: Fredrik: Some mix of being computed quickly and causing low collisions.

Comment: mgilson: today I learned. Thank you. Post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @EarlBellinger - to notify someone, add an `@` sign infront of their ID just like I did now :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, if all the elements of a tuple can be hashed, so can the tuple.  As such,

```
hash(tup)
```

should work just fine (and it'll be implemented in a way that is considered optimal by the python implementation developers).

Comment: More importantly, it is implemented in a way that works well with the dict implementation. The requirements on a hash function vary significantly depending on how the hash table resolves collisions.